# GHC crashes while compiling

Tags: haskell, ghc

```
module Main where

newtype Rec a b = Rec {deRec :: Rec a b -> a}

infixl 1 >|>
infixl 1 <|<
(>|>) = Rec
(<|<) (Rec x) = x

fix f = (\x -> f (x <|< x)) (Rec (\x -> f (x <|< x)))
factorial = fix (\f x -> if x<=1 then 1 else x*f(x-1))

main = do 
   x <- getLine
   putStrLn (show (factorial (read x)))
```

GHC response:

```
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 7.6.3 for x86_64-apple-darwin):
    Simplifier ticks exhausted
    When trying UnfoldingDone a_sMx{v} [lid]
    To increase the limit, use -fsimpl-tick-factor=N (default 100)
    If you need to do this, let GHC HQ know, and what factor you needed
    To see detailed counts use -ddump-simpl-stats
    Total ticks: 7121

Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I can reproduce this with Ubuntu (GHC version 7.6.3 for x86_64-unknown-linux). I think you have no reason not to report it. I'd report it, but as it's your bug, I'll leave the credits up to you. However, this *might* be only a case of increasing `-fsimpl-tick-factor`

Comment: The bug still occurs if replacing everything inside main with `print "foo"` and removing `factorial`.

Comment: With `-fsimpl-tick-factor=25000` (250 times the default value!) the error still occurs. More than that causes thrashing for me. Looks like infinite iterative unfolding of some of your constructs. Where did you get that code from (is it your own?)

Comment: @UliKöhler This is my own code and it worked fine in GHCi.

Comment: This is indeed quite strange. To my knowledge, the relevant optimizer code is the same in GHC as it is in GHCi.

Comment: this is a known problem.  GHC can't handle `newtype` with negative recursive uses.

Comment: Looks like a variation on the the simplifier problem which is documented.

Comment: @PhilipJF Can you provide a link?

Comment: @augustss Can you provide a link?

Comment: The problem is caused by the simplifier: try disabling that with e.g. `-O0` or some `NOINLINE` pragmas.

Comment: @Eric See Gabriel Gonzales answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is related to a known bug.  See Section 14.2 of the `ghc` manual:

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/bugs.html

I'll reproduce the relevant section here:

> GHC's inliner can be persuaded into non-termination using the standard way to encode recursion via a data type:

```
data U = MkU (U -> Bool)

russel :: U -> Bool
russel u@(MkU p) = not $ p u

x :: Bool
x = russel (MkU russel)
```

> We have never found another class of programs, other than this contrived one, that makes GHC diverge, and fixing the problem would impose an extra overhead on every compilation. So the bug remains un-fixed. There is more background in [Secrets of the GHC inliner](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/inlining/).

In other words, this bug arises when you use recursion in the negative position (i.e. the argument of a function).  From the manual, it appears that they have no intention of fixing this.

Comment: You linked to the 6.12 manual; [that text is still there, unchanged, in the 7.6.2 user manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/bugs.html), although the section it's in is now numbered 14.2.  (Also, [here's the Secrets of the GHC inliner link](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/inlining/).)

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned earlier, the problem arises when GHC's inliner working with function with parameters of recursive types. This can be workarounded with `NOINLINE` pragma. In your case:

```
{-# NOINLINE (<|<) #-}
```